# bringing submodules up to date with git

Tags: git

I have some services that all share a common submodule.

I qwould like to be able to automate bringing all the submodules to the last revision, so I made a script that does this:

> git submodule update --recursive --remote

but what is does it bring the submodules to the last revision and they are detached from Master, so I had to manually do a fast forward to master afterwards.

How can I being all submodules to the master head from the command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to bring all submodules up to their current `master`:

```
git submodule foreach 'git checkout master; git pull'
```

Once this completes, you will need to commit those changes in the parent repository.